# android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

In my app,i get this error :

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment kostas.menu.rssreader.BaseActivity$SampleListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I have an activity called BaseActivity in order to present a Sliding Menu (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

When i get out of my app (From the open sliding menu view),using the menu button, i get this error as i return!

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is declared as an instance class of your Activity, so the framework can't access it:

```
 class SampleListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
   ...
 }
```

The easiest way to deal with this is to move the fragment to its own file. This actually makes more sense since you probably want the same menu in several activities.

Note that this constructor will never be used. Android never uses any constructor other than the empty constructor for Activities.

```
 public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
   mTitleRes = titleRes;
 }
```

Comment: Wait, I should have noticed before but it actually seems like you're trying to use an Activity instead of a Fragment?

Comment: i want this menu only in one activity,not in several!

Comment: what to you mean to move it to its own file??the SlidingFragmentActivity i extend is part of my sliding menu library..

Comment: I meant to move the `SampleListFragment` out of that class.